# How do I batch delete a specific subfolder from multiple folders?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

Here's the "not-working" version of what I'm trying to do:

```
rd d:\Video\*\Sample /s /q
```

I've got a bunch of subfolders with different names within my "Video" folder, and some of them have a sub-subfolder called Sample in them. I want to delete the Sample folders and everything in them.

I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the answer by Bali C [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800575/delete-files-in-subfolder-using-batch-script). I'm not a batch expert, but that seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: RD will not delete folders with files in them as a safety measure.  do they have files?

Comment: Yup, they have a single file in them, which unfortunately always has a different name.

Comment: However, they do have the word "sample" in them, so I can just use: `del *sample* /s` to get rid of them first.

Comment: Why not PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

```
for /d /r "d:\Video" %a in (Sample) do if exist "%~fa\" echo rd "%~fa" /s /q
```

For each folder under the indicated one and below if a folder named `Sample` exists, remove it

If you don't need/want the recursive search, only want to process the folders inside `d:\Video`, then

```
for /d %a in ("d:\Video\*") do if exist "%~fa\Sample\" echo rd "%~fa\Sample" /s /q
```

For each folder under `d:\Video`, if it contains a folder named `Sample` then remove it.

**notes**:

- Both commands are coded to be executed from command line. From batch files the percent signs need to be doubled
- `rd` commands include a `echo` prefix, so the command is not executed, only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo`